Can you help me understand the curve in this piano score?
I am learning piano by myself; working on the following passages of Deşifre Çalışması:





I can't understand the curves (marked in white) on this page:

Can you help me?

Most of the curves (or "slurs") on these pages are just telling you to play the notes smoothly and connectedly. There's one special case, though: when there's a slur between two of the exact same pitches, that's a "tie," and it means you should hold the note for the extra length without hitting it a second time. For instance, 2 quarter notes (crotchets) connected by a tie sound exactly the same as one half note (minim). You can see this at the bottom of the first page. It's written this way because there was no room in the measure for more than one beat.

The meaning of the slur you indicated in white in the first system is: even though you play the first 4 notes (in the treble clef) with the right hand and the next 5 notes (in the bass clef) with the left hand, all 9 notes need to sound connected as one long phrase.
Musically, you should see that long phrase is a variation of the 2 preceding phrases, which are 2 parts of that long phrase now connected into one.
The last 3 notes in the treble clef (the C4 E4 D4) would be considered a second voice and are not part of the slurred notes.
Yes, the slur encompasses 4 measures.  The slur is a little unusual because it spans both staves and thus applies to both hands.
Similar meaning of the slur in

Passage #1 2nd system
Passage #2 measures 5-7


thank you so much, I asked so many people but now I understand very well

@sakura Glad we can help.  Good luck in your piano studies.

Thank you for your kind wishes.

It's basically the same as the other curves. They're phrases, which is the same as saying you'd sing all those notes in one breath, rather like speaking a phrase.
Try to keep all those notes as one 'sentence', and it'll all flow beautifully.

Does this curve encompass these four measures?

All the notes encompassed by the curve (slur) from the 1st to the last will belong to the phrase.
